# Nullable double NaN comparison in C#

Tags: c#, double, nan

I have 2 nullable doubles, an expected value and an actual value (let's call them value and valueExpected). A percentage is found using 100 * (value / valueExpected). However, if valueExpected is zero, it returns NaN. Everything good so far.

Now, what do I do if I need to check the value, to see if it is NaN? Normally one could use:

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(myDouble))
```

But this doesn't work with nullable values (IsNaN only works with non-nullable variables). I have changed my code to do the check (valueExpected == 0), but I'm still curious - is there any way to check for a nullable NaN?

**Edit:** When I say the code doesn't work, I mean it won't compile. Testing for null first doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With all [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) instances, you first check the [`bool HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) property, and then you can access the [`T Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property.

```
double? d = 0.0;        // Shorthand for Nullable<double>
if (d.HasValue && !Double.IsNaN(d.Value)) {
    double val = d.Value;

    // val is a non-null, non-NaN double.
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is just visual studio that is preventing me. I did have something like:
`
    if(myDouble != null)
    {
        if (!Double.IsNaN(myDouble))
        {
            //Do stuff!
        }
    }
`
But this and your code doesn't compile, it still doesn't like using IsNaN, even after the 'is null' check.

Comment: Did you see the ".Value" after the variable name "d". d.Value is a double and it should definitely compile.

Comment: My code compiles just fine. The "is null" check you added doesn't change anything. Your code is still incorrect. `myDouble` is a `Nullable<double>` while `IsNaN()` expects a `double`. You **must** use the `.Value` property.

Comment: Ah! Yep, that works. So the .value will use it as a non-nullable type. Thanks! I missed the .value.

Comment: Did you happen to check out the documentation? MSDN is your best friend when it comes to these things. `.Value` actually returns the *actual* underlying value. `Nullable<T>` is really just a `T` and a `bool` under the hood.

Comment: I've never actually used the Nullable<double> notation, I've always used the double? way, which made it difficult to search. But I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to upvote any answer that helped, and accept the one that best answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(myDouble ?? 0.0))
```

The value in the inner-most parenthesis is either the `myDouble` (with its `Nullable<>` wrapping removed) if that is non-null, or just `0.0` if `myDouble` is `null`. Se [`??` Operator (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it with casting the double? with double

```
double.IsNaN((double)myDouble)
```

this will return true if NaN and false if not

Comment: Note that this will not work (throw an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`) whenever `myDouble == null` which is the point of having a nullable...

Answer (score 0):

With C# 7.0 [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) combined null + NaN check check can be written like this:

```
double? d = whatever;
if(d is double val && double.IsNaN(val))
   Console.WriteLine(val);
```

The advantage is local scoped variable `val` at hand, which is not `null`, nor `double.NaN` and can even be used outside of `if`.

Answer (score 0):

With pattern matching in [newer Roslyn C# versions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/71a87eca6c65dbda7ec58daa6d4cfdc7cd310dbc), `double.NaN` is a valid pattern which tests using `IsNaN` (that is it works differently than `Equals()` where `NaN` is never equal to `NaN` as specified by IEEE floating point standard).

Therefore you can now do this:

```cs
double? myDouble = something;
if (myDouble is double and not double.NaN)
   Console.WriteLine("A number");
```

For testing `NaN` this can even be shortened like this:

```cs
double? myDouble = something;
if (myDouble is double.NaN)
   Console.WriteLine("Not a number and not NULL");
```